# php multiple if conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

when i try to filter all these parameters php only enters in the first if conditions, ignoring all others conditions.

```
if($t_red<0){
    $t_red=0;
}

else if($t_red>256){
    $t_red=255;
}

else if($t_green<0){
    $t_red=0;
}

else if($t_green>256){
    $t_red=255;
}

if($t_blue<0){
    $t_red=0;
}

if($t_blue>256){
    $t_red=255;
}

if($t_red<0){
    $t_red=0;
}
```

Comment: what seems to be the question?

Comment: `else` statements only run if the `if` is false.  Also, why does each `if` have `$t_red=`?

Comment: what is the value of $t_red,$t_green and $t_blue? maybe you should group some of those conditions

Answer (score 7):

Probably best suited if ran through a filtering function.

```
function setParam($param) {
  if($param < 0) {
    $param = 0;
  } elseif($param > 256) {
    $param = 255;
  }

  return $param;
}

$t_green = setParam($t_green);
$t_red = setParam($t_red);
$t_blue = setParam($t_blue);
```

You could also use pass-by-reference if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I *think* that you would want to remove the `else` before the third `if` statement and add an `else` before the sixth `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t_red=$t_red<0?0;$t_red;
$t_red=$t_red>=256?255;$t_red;


//are you sure you're modifying t_red here? and not t_green?
$t_red=$t_green<0?0;$t_red;
$t_red=$t_green>=256?255;$t_red;

//are you sure you're modifying t_red here? and not t_blue?
$t_red=$t_blue<0?0;$t_red;
$t_red=$t_blue>=256?255;$t_red;
```

Comment: you mean to put : in a few places e.g. $t_red=$t_red<0?0:$t_red;

Answer (score 0):

a successfully met condition of an if (or following else if) statement will ignore all else if/else statements that immediately follow it, but the if statements afterwards are executing - You can verify this by adding echo statement to each one . Could it perhaps be because all your variable assignments are for $t_red so no action is taken on $t_green or $t_blue?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($t_red < 0)
{
    $t_red = 0;
}
else if($t_red > 255) //Original won't catch it if it is == to 256, have to do either >= 256 or > 255
{
    $t_red = 255;
}

if($t_green < 0)
{
    $t_green = 0;
}
else if($t_green > 255)
{
    $t_green = 255;
}

if($t_blue < 0)
{
    $t_blue = 0;
}
else if($t_blue > 255)
{
    $t_blue = 255;
}
```

Andrew Sledge's answer is the best though, but I did correct the fact that it would miss correcting the value if it was == to 256, which wouldn't be caught by just `$var > 256`, and thus would be in error if the value has to be between 0 and 255.